# Block access to multiple files with .htaccess - RewriteRule and FilesMatch fail

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite, nginx

I am trying to block access to specific files.  Neither the RewriteRule or FilesMatch rules I have tried work on the live server, it serves the files as normal with status  200 OK (I'm expecting 404 Not Found).

The regex I am using for FilesMatch is `(?:test|readme|license|changelog|-config|-sample)\.(?:php|md|txt|html?)`.  I have tested it at https://regexr.com/ and it is successful for

- /readme.html
- /wp-content/test.txt
- /_test/test.txt

I have also tested the `RewriteRule` at https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/.  It is successful for URL `https://www.example.com/readme.html` and `https://www.example.com/wp-content/test.txt` with .htaccess rule `RewriteRule (?:test|readme|license|changelog|-config|-sample)\.(?:php|md|txt|html?) - [R=404,NC,L]`.

I have seen the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51132806/3204075 The following does not work for me, I still get 200 OK for `readme.html` and `test.txt` in the root directory.

```
<filesMatch "(readme\.html|test\.txt)">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</filesMatch>
```

Can anyone suggest why the following `FilesMatch` and `RewriteRule`s appear to be ignored by Apache?

RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule (?:test|readme|license|changelog|-config|-sample)\.(?:php|md|txt|html?) - [R=404,NC,L]
```

FilesMatch

```
<FilesMatch (?:test|readme|license|changelog|-config|-sample)\.(?:php|md|txt|html?)>
  # since apache 2.4: Require all denied
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Environment

- Cloudways
- Nginx 1.19.8-0
- Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Do you have other directives? Are `.htaccess` overrides enabled in the server config? Have you confirmed you are not seeing a cached response? How does Nginx fit into this picture? If it is being used as a front-end proxy to serve static content then it is going to do just that and bypass your Apache server altogether.

Comment: @MrWhite - you were correct, I overlooked how Nginx sits in front of Apache and is configured separately.  I'm new to Linux, coming from 20 years of Windows servers.

Comment: Question revised as requested, I didn't realise it was acceptable to answer my own question.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was my own misunderstanding of how Nginx works with Apache.  The `.htaccess` rules appear not to work because they are never invoked as the request is handled by Nginx thus never reaches Apache.

For anyone else using Cloudways, it is not possible at this time for custom Nginx rules to be added through the user control panel, the SSH console or by the Support Agents.

Support can however remove file extensions from the Nginx config eg. .html and .txt.  With requests for resources with these extensions now received by Apache, both the `FilesMatch` and `RewriteRule`s noted in the original question work as expected.